# If a method can throw multiple exceptions, how to declare it?

Tags: java, exception

I think `throws Exception` only handles the general case.

If my method can throw multiple exceptions, how to declare it?

Comment: What's wrong with comma? [further reading](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public writeThisToFile(String line) throws FileNotFoundException, AppSpecificServiceException, SecurityException{
 /* some thing */
}
```

---

**See Also**

- [§ 8.4.6 Method Throws](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#308526)

Answer (score 7):

```
public void yourMethod() throws anException, anotherException {
 //stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `throws` clause:

```
public void myMethod()
    throws Exception1, Exception2
{
    ...
}
```